# MS Access using textbox value in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I got a simple form containing 1 textbox and 1 button.

Now I wanna use this function:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION fnFietsAantDagenPerJaar
        (
            @Jaar AS int

        )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN

    SELECT f.Fiets_id, f.Fiets_Type, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)) AantalDagen
    FROM Fiets f
        INNER JOIN HuurovereenkomstFiets hf
        ON hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = f.Fiets_id
        INNER JOIN Huurovereenkomst h
        ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id
    WHERE YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum) = @Jaar AND YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum) = @Jaar
    GROUP BY f.Fiets_id, f.Fiets_Type

    GO
```

As a pass-through using the function and take the value from the textbox as the variable. 
or this query:

```
    SELECT f.Fiets_id, f.Fiets_Type, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)) AantalDagen
    FROM Fiets f
        INNER JOIN HuurovereenkomstFiets hf
        ON hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = f.Fiets_id
        INNER JOIN Huurovereenkomst h
        ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id
    GROUP BY f.Fiets_id, f.Fiets_Type
```

And make it have this WHERE statement;

```
WHERE YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum) = Textbox1 AND 
YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum) = Textbox1
```

I can't find out how to do it with either solutions, does anyone have a idea how to use a textbox value in my query to get the results?

Answer (score 1):

That could be:

```
WHERE YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum) = [Forms]![YourForm]![Textbox1] AND 
YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum) = [Forms]![YourForm]![Textbox1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gustav, you are my hero!